# Change the div content of a form on checkbox select?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have two checkboxes `First` and `Second`

```
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" /> First

    <br />

    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" /> Seconf
```

And two forms `Form1`

```
    <form>
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="first">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="">Phone</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

and `Form 2`

```
    <form>
    <div class="form-row">

        <div class="form-group col-md-6">
        <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>
        </div>
    </div>
    </form>
```

When the `first` form is selected - display the `first form` content, Similarly for the `second` - `Second form`.

https://codepen.io/thorstorm/pen/vYNpNYr

I saw many answers reg show/hide and only single form content. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

Comment: Please update your question with your JavaScript and explain what's not working with what you've tried.

Comment: What have you tried? We expect that you'll make an effort at solving your problem before posting. And then, when you do post, that your question will be about a specific problem you're having with your attempt, rather than "How do I do this?"

Comment: use the `.onchange` event listener to do that

Comment: Sorry, Pretty new to html. Will update what I have worked on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I made this for you

```js
var form1 = document.querySelector("#f1"),
    form2 = document.querySelector("#f2"),
    check1 = document.querySelector("#checkbox1"),
    check2 = document.querySelector("#checkbox2");

check1.onchange = function() {
  form1.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
check2.onchange = function() {
  form2.classList.toggle("hidden");
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox1" id="checkbox1" value="checkbox1" checked/> First

<br />

<input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" value="checkbox2" checked/> Second

<form id="f1">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="first">Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" required>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="phone" name="phone" required>
  </div>
</div>
</form>

<form id="f2">
<div class="form-row">

  <div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="inputCity">Address</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" name="address" required>
  </div>
  </div>
</form>
```